# R- Mutate multiple iterations with incremental variable name within for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am attempting to have multiple mutates within a for loop, but each of the mutate should create a new variable in an increasing numeric. Am I able to do this within one block of code without repeating the same line with the new variable name? In this example, I am attempting to find the datediff between 2 dates within each mutuate function

ex:

```
for (i in c(1:nrow(pd))) 
{
  result <- pd %>%
    mutate(n1.DateDiff = abs(difftime(pd[i,]$`Date(US)`, n1.Status_dt, units = c("days"))), 
            n2.DateDiff = abs(difftime(pd[i,]$`Date(US)`, n2.Status_dt, units = c("days"))),    
             n3.DateDiff = abs(difftime(pd[i,]$`Date(US)`, n3.Status_dt, units = c("days")))) 
}
```

Ideally, I'd like one line where I'm able to loop and create n1-n3 without writing this in 3 lines.

Comment: `difftime` is vectorized.  Not clear why you need a loop for rows.   Can you show a small reproducible example using `dput` i.e. something like `pd <- pd %>% mutate(across(ends_with('Status_dt'), ~ abs(difftime(`Date(US)`, .x, units = "days")), .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'Status_dt', 'DateDiff')}"))`

Answer (score 1):

The `across` pattern recommended by @akrun is the way such problems are intended to be solved. But if you want to use a for loop, perhaps you are looking for something like the following:

```r
in_cols = c("n1.Stats_dt", "n2.Stats_dt", "n3.Stats_dt")
out_cols = c("n1.DateDiff", "n2.DateDiff", "n3.DateDiff")

for(ii in 1:3){
  this_in = in_cols[ii]
  this_out = out_cols[ii]

  df = df %>%
    mutate(!!sym(this_out) := difftime(pd, !!sym(this_in)))
}
```

Notes:

- `!!sym(.)` is used to turn a text string into a variable
- `:=` is equivalen to `=` but allows us to use `!!sym(.)` on the left-hand side